# How can we maintain session in a Perl CGI web application?

Tags: perl, session, cgi

How to manage user session in Perl CGI web application? Is there any way other than cookies, hidden fields. Is there any possibility?

Comment: Cookies and hidden fields are pretty much it with any web application regardless of language. Check out CGI::Session http://search.cpan.org/~sherzodr/CGI-Session-3.95/Session.pm though. It makes it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a Perl web framework that you like and use its session plugin. Most of the frameworks have some way to handle this for you. There are ways other than cookies, but they're fairly ugly and sometimes sneaky.

If you don't like that, there's plenty of documentation and examples waiting for you to read after you click-through on your Google search. The topic is rather large and could probably fill a small book. Since you're question is very broad, you're unlikely to get help on Stackoverflow.

You can also search CPAN for [modules with Session](https://www.metacpan.org/search?q=session) in the name. For web frameworks, you might consider [Mojolicious](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojolicious), [Dancer](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Dancer), [Catalyst](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Catalyst), and others. Their documentation will lead you to their session handling features.

Comment: Your suggestion worked out for me.I am java developer.I am very new to perl.I am going to use  use CGI::Session.Thank you very much brain.